# How can I remove empty objects from JSON array in iOS?

Tags: ios, json

How can I remove empty objects from JSON array in iOS?

```
[
   {"latitude":"", "longtitude":""},
   {"latitude":"13.0856", "longtitude":"70.2423"},
   {"latitude":"13.0856", "longtitude":"70.2423"}
]
```

The first pair of latitude and longitude in this array is invalid, so when I try to display all coordinates from this array in mapview, the first point lands somewhere in the sea, which is why I'd like to remove that point from the array.

How do I go about that?

Comment: Convert the JSON into NSMutableDictionary, get values of objects, see if they are empty. If they are, remove them.

Comment: if it is empty do nothing else continue your process

Comment: This is not a valid dictionary. Keys must be unique.

Comment: @ozgur is correct, as of your latest edit, your dictionary is invalid. If you have to use same key anyways, it should be an array of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can remove it while converting JSON in to Dictionary.

In **SWIFT** Write like,

```
let dict : NSMutableDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(operation.HTTPRequestOperation.responseData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSMutableDictionary
if(dict.valueForKey("customer_latitude") as! String == "" && dict.valueForKey("customer_longtitude") as! String == "")
{
       // Don't add value
}
else
{
       // Your code here
}
```

Hope this will help you.